# Angular 13 creating library as per documentation fails on lint

Tags: angular

While learning the new Angular 13 approach to creating libraries and following their documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) all goes as described up to the step of:

```
ng lint my-lib
```

These steps are taken and the error appears at the end:

**An unhandled exception occurred: Project target does not exist.**

```
    Cannot find "lint" target for the specified project.

    You should add a package that implements linting capabilities.

    For example:
      ng add @angular-eslint/schematics

    Would you like to add ESLint now? Yes
    i Using package manager: npm
    √ Found compatible package version: @angular-eslint/schematics@13.0.1.
    √ Package information loaded.


    The package @angular-eslint/schematics@13.0.1 will be installed and executed.
    Would you like to proceed? Yes
    √ Package successfully installed.

        All @angular-eslint dependencies have been successfully installed 

        Please see https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint for how to add ESLint configuration to your project.


        We detected that you have a single project in your workspace and no existing linter wired up, so we are configuring ESLint for you automatically.

        Please see https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint for more information.

    CREATE projects/twi-lib-a02/.eslintrc.json (852 bytes)
    UPDATE package.json (1482 bytes)
    UPDATE angular.json (1517 bytes)
    √ Packages installed successfully.
    An unhandled exception occurred: Project target does not exist.
```

in the file: angular.json I see:

```
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
      "options": {
        "lintFilePatterns": [
          "projects/my-lib/**/*.ts",
          "projects/my-lib/**/*.html"
        ]
      }
    }
"defaultProject": "my-lib",
"cli": {
  "defaultCollection": "@angular-eslint/schematics"
}
```

I tried generating a sample application and configure it as a possible target, but instead getting more errors.

Would you please explain what is missing here and possibly complete the steps Angular documentation is not providing?

Comment: Your default project is library so dont provide the name while running the command. Simply run "ng lint" and it will work.

Comment: Tried, got error:  An unhandled exception occurred: Failed to load config "../../.eslintrc.json" to extend from.

Comment: Looks like your eslint configure has not been setup correctly.

Comment: I am just following the instructions and prompts without any modifications.